# How to read Applications and Services Logs via WMI?

Tags: powershell, wmi

I can get all event log messages via WMI in powershell like

```
Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'Security'"
```

To enumerate all event logs I use

```
Get-WmiObject win32_nteventlogfile
FileSize LogfileName            Name                                                        NumberOfRecords
-------- -----------            ----                                                        ---------------
26218496 Application            C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Application.evtx                      75510
   69632 HardwareEvents         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\HardwareEvents.evtx                       0
   69632 Internet Explorer      C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Internet Explorer.evtx                    0
   69632 Key Management Service C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Key Management Service.evtx               0
   69632 OAlerts                C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\OAlerts.evtx                             39
   69632 Parameters             C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Parameters.evtx                           0
12652544 Security               C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx                         18840
   69632 State                  C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\State.evtx                                0
 8458240 System                 C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\System.evtx                           15108
   69632 Windows Azure          C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Windows Azure.evtx                        0
 2166784 Windows PowerShell     C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Windows PowerShell.evtx                1656
```

So far found not a way to parse all other logs showing up under Applications and Service Logs

[image]

With Powershell I can get the log files via

```
Get-WinEvent -ListLog *

LogMode   MaximumSizeInBytes RecordCount LogName
-------   ------------------ ----------- -------
Circular            15728640        1656 Windows PowerShell
Circular             1052672           0 Windows Azure
Circular            20971520       15123 System
Circular            20971520       19404 Security
Circular             1052672          39 OAlerts
Circular            20971520           0 Key Management Service
Circular             1052672           0 Internet Explorer
Circular            20971520           0 HardwareEvents
Circular            26214400       75525 Application
Circular             1052672           0 WitnessClientAdmin
Circular             1052672             Windows Networking Vpn Plugin Platform/OperationalVerbose
Circular             1052672             Windows Networking Vpn Plugin Platform/Operational
Circular             1052672           0 SMSApi
Circular             1052672          66 Setup
Circular             1052672           0 OpenSSH/Operational
Circular             1052672           0 OpenSSH/Admin
Circular             1052672             Network Isolation Operational
Circular             1052672           0 Microsoft-WS-Licensing/Admin
Circular             1052672           0 Microsoft-WindowsPhone-Connectivity-WiFiConnSvc-Channel
Circular             1052672           0 Microsoft-Windows-WWAN-SVC-Events/Operational
```

But when I try to read other log files then I get nothing. When I try to read e.g. the Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience/Program-Compatibility-Assistant file I get nothing back:

```
Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience/Program-Compatibility-Assistant'"
```

The log file has a different name

```
 Directory of C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs

12/26/2019  07:55 PM            69,632 Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience%4Program-Compatibility-Assistant.evtx
```

In the event viewer the name is displayed as

[image]

What would be the correct log file name I need to enter to the WMI query to read the events?

Comment: Is this still an issue? `Get-WinEvent "Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience/Program-Compatibility-Assistant"` is returning the events as expected.  
However, `Win32_NTLogEventLog` doesn't work, you have ot use `wevtutil.exe export-log "Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience/Program-Compatibility-Assistant"` to export the logs...

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never I guess.

Create the following key in registry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Microsoft-Windows-Program-Compatibility-Assistant/Analytic`

No values required, just the key.
You should then be able to run a query like this

```
select * from Win32_NTLogEvent where logfile = 'Microsoft-Windows-Program-Compatibility-Assistant/Analytic'
```

Comment: I have created the key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Microsoft-Windows-Program-Compatibility-Assistant/Analytic but the query still return 0 hits

Comment: Does the logfile actually hold data? Could you tell me what it actually logs? I can't test it in my environment as the logfile is empty for me.

Comment: After the change, on one of my customer's machines, entries are no longer written to the log file. It shows there are no entries then never receives new entries.  Has anyone seen this behavior.

Comment: I have seen this as well.  For my customer this issue is specific to logs with spaces in the name.  I tried escaping the event log names with %20 but that didn't work either.